# what is ignition in NvM?

Tags: persistence, autosar, non-volatile

I cannot understand what "ignition" means.

> Persistency offers mechanisms to Adaptive Applications to store information in the non-volatile memory of a machine. The data is available over boot and ignition cycles.

I think, "ignition" means that the data is loaded from persistent memory like HDD, SSD. Is it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context it means power off / power on.